# Combining data from different rows to a string

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am getting data from a single column in a datatable. I need it to be combine to a string separated by comma or any delimiter.

The end result should be a string instead of the tabular data.

```
let words = datatable(word:string, code:string) [
"apple","A",
"orange","B",
"grapes","C"
];
words | project word;
```

I need to combine the result combined into a string with a delimiter.

Result should be : `"apple,orange,grapes"`

Comment: try this: words 
| summarize makelist(word) , but it will have the string inside [].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try combining `strcat_array()` with `summarize make_list()` as follows:

```
let words = datatable(word:string, code:string) [
    "apple","A",
    "orange","B",
    "grapes","C"
];
words
| summarize result = strcat_array(make_list(word), ",")
```

this returns a single table with a single string column, whose value is: `apple,orange,grapes`