# how to reduce rows to 1 row by concatenate in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics

- string row1
- string row2

Is it possible to reduce rows to 1 row?
Rows should be joined with a comma.
As a result I expect

- string row1, string row2

Comment: You can try `strcat()` or `strcat_array()` or `strcat_delim()`. Reference: [Combining data from different rows to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472695/combining-data-from-different-rows-to-a-string), [strcat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcatfunction) and [strcat_delim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcat-delimfunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workaround could able to solve the above issue,

To concatenate we can use this for e.g `| extend New_Column = strcat(tagname,",", tagvalue)` with comma between two string.

For example we have tested in our environment with tag name and tag value

```
  resourcecontainers      
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | extend tagname = tostring(bag_keys(tags)[0])
    | extend tagvalue = tostring(tags[tagname])
    | extend New_Column = strcat(tagname,",", tagvalue) // for concate two rows into one with comma between two string
```

Here is the sample output for reference:
[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472695/combining-data-from-different-rows-to-a-string)

***UPDATE***: To cancat the rows we tried  with the example of code as stated in the given SO THREAD which is suggested by @Yoni L.

```
| summarize result = strcat_array(make_list(word), ",")
```

Sample output for reference:
[image]

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the tips. in your links I found:
| summarize result = strcat_array(make_list(name_s), ",")